# Mounting many davfs2 webdav on same server making webdav slow

Tags: mount, nextcloud, davfs2

I did setup a gnome mate desktop server using thinlinc. And behind it, i do have a nextcloud server for the file handling. I wanted to have at each remote desktop access to nextcloud server by using a mounted webdav drive, using davfs2. This works nicely, but when i finally mounted 7-9 drives, so on each remote desktop one webdav drive. Things start to slow down dramatically. It looks like davfs2 can't handle many drives at ones at the same server, or that apache can't handle these connections at ones, even tough it basicly runs locally? I'm out of idea's. And i don't know where to look for answers. So why is there a limit to how many webdav drives can be mounted on the same server nextcloud is installed also?

Comment: Did you find a way to speed things up? I'm looking for months but could not find anything. And it's even slow with a single share mounted for me. Part of the slowness seems to be it does a lot of [recursive checks](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/webdav-extremely-slow-on-linux-using-davfs2-mount/123811) – but there doesn't seem to be an option to disable that.